# i'm not getting how to link two tables with a primary and a foreign key

Tags: php, session, pdo

I have two tables, one is called "reg" for registered users in my website, the reg table has a primary key which is "phone", after registering and logging in, a table called "offered_rides" gets populated when the user fills in a form , and the offered_rides has a foreign key "phone", i can't wrap my head around how will the offered_rides get it's foreign key "phone" value when the user fills in the form, i'm having a hard time connecting the two, here is the insert statement for both:

"reg"

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO reg (fname,lname,phone,email,password,gender)"
                                  . " VALUES (:fname, :lname,:phone, :email, :hashedpass, :gender)");

              $stmt->bindParam(':fname',$fname);
              $stmt->bindParam(':lname',$lname);
              $stmt->bindParam(':phone',$phone);
              $stmt->bindParam(':email',$email);
              $stmt->bindParam(':hashedpass',$hashedpass); 
              $stmt->bindParam(':gender',$gender);
              
              $stmt->execute();
```

"offered_rides"

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO offered_rides(start, finish, date, seats, time, location)"
                . " VALUES (:start, :finish,:date, :seats, :time, :location)");

            $stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
            $stmt->bindParam(':finish', $finish);
            $stmt->bindParam(':date', $date);
            $stmt->bindParam(':seats', $seats);
            $stmt->bindParam(':time', $time);
            $stmt->bindParam(':location', $location);
            
            $stmt->execute();
```

notice i'm not inserting anything in the phone column in offered_rides, i don't know what to insert and how to insert it, how can my system know that this person filling the form is the person with the phone number they logged in with.

Comment: that is really not much to go on, if you have the id of the person you always can add (SELECT phone FROM reg WHERE id = session(id) and add it to the insert as variable

Comment: why not store the phone number in a session then put it in the select statement instead of taking it from the parent table? is this even a good practice? how would you do it yourself?

Comment: `phone` seems like a strange thing to use as the primary key. What if you have two users who live in the same house and share a phone?

Comment: of course you can save the data in the session when you log in

Comment: @Barmar you're probably right, i'll change it, but i still don't know how to connect both whatever the primary key was. is nbk's solution a good practice?

Comment: When the user logs in, you store the primary key in a session variable. Then you can use that in all your queries during the login session.